# Function or script on LHS of the equation in python

Tags: python, cocotb

I have a requirement on cocotb similar to below :

```
x = "a"
x = 2 => This should become a = 2
```

Can someone please help whether would it be possible to achieve this in python ?
I need to assign values to DUT (like below) based on the above approach:

```
for sig in ["sig_1", "sig_2"]:
    self.bfm.sig = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried `self.bfm[sig]=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m pretty sure you don’t want to be doing this in your code, but what you are trying to do can be accomplished using `eval()`:

```
for sig in ["sig_1", "sig_2"]:
    eval(f”self.bfm.{sig} = 1”)
```

This will also work with your MWE at the top of your question:

```
x = "a"
eval(f”{x} = 2”)
```

Note that this kind of use (or abuse) of `eval` goes against best practices. You’d probably be better off turning `bfm` into a dict, which is frankly made to accept strings as keys in the way you are trying to use them:

```
for sig in ["sig_1", "sig_2"]:
    self.bfm[sig] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Drphoton for the response.
But eval(f"{x} = 2") results in syntax error. Can you please help ?

Comment: I tried with exec and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

as Unmitigated commented:

```
for sig in ["sig_1", "sig_2"]:
    self.bfm[sig]=1
```

should do if you want 1 for both of them `"sig_1", "sig_2"`

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets.

```py
for sig in ["sig_1", "sig_2"]:
    self.bfm[sig] = 1
```